# C++ MFC OwnerDrawn CListBox with an embedded control

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, mfc

Using C++ MFC, and having a `CListBox` which is owner drawn, I have text and also a `CLinkCtrl` in each list box item. My problem is that the `CLinkCtrl` is not always the control that I expect to see when scrolling up and down, while the text that is owner drawn is always correct.

There exists another bug, where one of the list items at the bottom is almost always not showing the link control.

Here are some screenshots:

// this is before scrolling, and the list item links are in correct order
[image]

// here is after scrolling, where the list link items **are** not in the correct order

[image]

When I select a control, the UI is updated at times with the correct control values.

I will try and add as much possible information, and hopefully enough to be able to see the bug.

There are three parts:

1: ListBox Configuration, make it owner drawn

2: Populate the ListBox, which adds "Items" to `CListBox`:
**The code below has been updated**, by uncommenting the thread usage; UI updates should be consistent from the main thread; `SendMessage` is allowed from a thread, but some parts is updating the `CListBox` directly.

```
 //std::thread t([=]() {
  //myMutex.lock();  // acquire the mutex

  // Disable redrawing of the control...
  calListBox.EnableWindow(FALSE);
  calListBox.SetRedraw(FALSE);

  // clear all the items
  for (int i = 0; i < calListBox.GetCount(); i++)
  {
    LPARAM lpData = calListBox.GetItemData(i);
    CalListBoxItem* item = reinterpret_cast<CalListBoxItem*>(lpData);
    delete item;
  }
  calListBox.ResetContent();

  // for loop
    int index = calListBox.SendMessage(LB_ADDSTRING, 0, 0);
    if (index == LB_ERR) {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
    }
    else {
        CalListBoxItem* pItem = new CalListBoxItem(description, htmllink, index);
        calListBox.SendMessage(LB_SETITEMDATA, index, reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(pItem));
        calListBox.SendMessage(LB_SETITEMHEIGHT, index, 100);
    }
  // end for loop

    calListBox.SetRedraw(TRUE); // Re-enable redrawing of the control
    calListBox.EnableWindow(TRUE);      

    //myMutex.unlock();  // release the mutex
//});
//t.detach();
```

```
// here is the `CalListBoxItem`, it just holds the description, index and the htmllink control
public:
    ~CalListBoxItem();
    CalListBoxItem(const std::string& desc, const std::string& link, int index)
        : m_desc(desc), m_link(link), originalIndex(index)
    {
        linkCtrl = new CCustLinkCtrl();
    }

public:
    int originalIndex;
    CCustLinkCtrl* linkCtrl;

    std::string m_desc;
    std::string m_link;
```

3: There is the `CListBox` which most part is about drawing the list items,
some of it drawing text, which works 100%, it's just the control that I add which has some randomness.

Here are some of the bits for the Custom `CalListBox` which extends `CListBox`

```
// The AddLinkCtrl function
void CalListBox::AddLinkControl(CLinkCtrl* linkCtrl, CRect& rect, int nItemIndex, CString text, CString htmlLink) {

    if (!linkCtrl) {
        return;
    }

    if (::IsWindow(linkCtrl->m_hWnd)) { 
        CString strIndex;
        strIndex.Format(_T(" u:%d"), nItemIndex);  // convert nItemIndex to CString
        CString strText = text + strIndex;      // concatenate text and strIndex

        linkCtrl->SetWindowTextW(strText);
        linkCtrl->Invalidate();
        linkCtrl->UpdateWindow();
        return; // the control has already been created
    }

    // Create the control as a child of the list box
    linkCtrl->Create(_T(""), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | DT_VCENTER | SS_NOTIFY, rect, this, IDC_LINK_CTRL_LIST_ITEM + nItemIndex);

    CString strIndex;
    strIndex.Format(_T(" %d"), nItemIndex);  // convert nItemIndex to CString
    CString strText = text + strIndex;      // concatenate text and strIndex

    linkCtrl->SetWindowTextW(strText);

    //linkCtrl->SetWindowTextW(text + nItemIndex);
    linkCtrl->SetItemUrl(0, htmlLink); // must be after text is set, else the link does not work

    linkCtrl->SetFont(linkFont);
    linkCtrl->Invalidate();
    linkCtrl->UpdateWindow();
}
```

And here is the `DrawItem`, partial bits shown:

```
void CalListBox::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)
{
    if (lpDrawItemStruct->itemData == 0) {
        return;
    }

    /*
    CalListBoxItem* pItem = reinterpret_cast<CalListBoxItem*>(GetItemData(lpDrawItemStruct->itemID));
    if (pItem == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    */

    CalListBoxItem* pItem = reinterpret_cast<CalListBoxItem*>(lpDrawItemStruct->itemData);
    if (pItem == nullptr) {
        return;
    }

    CDC* pDC = CDC::FromHandle(lpDrawItemStruct->hDC);
    if (pDC == nullptr) {
        return;
    }

    // Clip the region, not to draw outside of the boundary
    /*
    CRgn clipRgn;
    clipRgn.CreateRectRgnIndirect(&lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem);
    pDC->SelectClipRgn(&clipRgn);
    */

    CRect rect(lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem);

    // snip 

    AddLinkControl(pItem->linkCtrl, leftRect2, pItem->originalIndex, L"<a>Link</a>", leftText2);
```

Comment: `std::thread t([=]() { ... }` - There's your issue. Don't update UI controls from any thread other than the thread owning the control.

Comment: That is interesting, I would have thought that I could update the UI using SendMessage? i.e. `calListBox.SendMessage(LB_SETITEMDATA, index, reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(pItem));`

Comment: I first tried removing the parts that clear the ListCtrl to the outer scope, before the thread starts, then I tried removing the thread entirely. The problem remained, but did alter the behaviour. This not something new, after the threading change: When I select(click) an Item from the ListCtrl the data becomes visibly correct (from wrong order to the correct order), but for some items the ListCtrl links become invisible/lost.

Comment: You can. `SendMessage` isn't the issue. That gets serialized by the system for you, meaning that you get single-thread performance at the expense of using two (virtual) cores. The issue is that you're `delete`-ing `CalListBoxItem`'s from one thread, while `CalListBox::DrawItem` accesses them from another thread, without any coordination. The results of doing this are unpredictable. Occasionally it will appear to "work just fine", when at other times it won't. It would help to understand what problem you are trying to solve in spinning up a thread.

Comment: I realize I need to do some more work with that part, that is to not do all operations in one thread - I need to only do the network blocking io in a thread, and when the thread returns update the UI from the main thread; But moving along for now I have removed the thread entirely. I will update the code in the question to what I have done - removing the thread entirely.

Comment: Sigh, Berkeley Sockets... The bane that has implanted the idea that networking must entertain blocking calls out of necessity. Here's an apparently little known fact. **ALL** I/O in Window is asynchronous, by default, and blocking I/O is opt-in. This includes networking, and MFC's [`CAsyncSocket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/casyncsocket-class) provides an abstraction over single-threaded, asynchronous networking I/O.